# composer require laravel/passport command error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I want to install composer require laravel/passport in a laravel API, it throws me the following errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v11.5.0, ..., v11.8.4] require league/oauth2-server ^8.2 -> satisfiable by league/oauth2-server[8.2.0, ..., 8.5.3].   
    - laravel/passport[v11.8.5, ..., v11.8.8] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.3|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0].
    - league/oauth2-server[8.5.2, ..., 8.5.3] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.3 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0].
    - laravel/passport[v0.1.0, ..., v0.2.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.18, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.11, v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.2, v4.0.0, ..., v4.0.3, v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.3, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.5.1] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.2).
    - laravel/passport[v8.0.0, ..., v8.5.0, v9.0.0, ..., v9.3.2] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/passport v9.4.0 requires illuminate/auth ^6.18.31|^7.22.4 -> found illuminate/auth[v6.18.31, ..., v6.20.44, v7.22.4, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., v10.2.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.2 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.3.0, ..., v10.3.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.2|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., 
v9.52.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.3.3, ..., v10.4.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.37|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.37.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v11.0.0, ..., v11.4.0] require illuminate/auth ^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - league/oauth2-server[8.2.0, ..., 8.5.1] require psr/http-message ^1.0.1 -> found psr/http-message[1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed 
to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command. 
    - lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0] require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport * -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v0.1.0, ..., v0.2.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.18, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.11, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.5.1,

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp3\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.   
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/passport:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/passport:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

the version of php that I use is `^8.1`

use the command`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and in the console it showed me the following:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi


  laravel/sail ....................................................................................................................... DONE  
  laravel/sanctum .................................................................................................................... DONE  
  laravel/tinker ..................................................................................................................... DONE  
  nesbot/carbon ...................................................................................................................... DONE  
  nunomaduro/collision ............................................................................................................... DONE  
  nunomaduro/termwind ................................................................................................................ DONE  
  spatie/laravel-ignition ............................................................................................................ DONE  

82 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

the laravel version is `10.15.0`and this is the composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
"keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

Comment: Share the file contents of your `composer.json` file as well.

Comment: "_require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension._" and "_To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - C:\xampp3\php\php.ini_" Enable that PHP extension

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? I believe you are using laravel 8 or less. If that is the case you need to downgrade your php version or upgrade laravel version

Comment: remove all the code in `composer.lock` and just set `{ }` braces and delete all vendor folder and run again

Answer (score 6):

Enable the sodium extension in your php.ini.

1. Edit your php.ini file at `C:\xampp3\php\php.ini`
2. Under *Dynamic Extensions* add:

```
extension=sodium
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing both the `composer.lock` file and the `vendor` directory, and then run the installation command again

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable the ext-sodium extension in your PHP configuration. Open your php.ini file (located at C:\xampp\php\php.ini for windows) and ensure that the following line is uncommented:  extension=sodium
2. Remove composer.lock and run "composer require laravel/passport" again.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Ignore Sodium Extension:** The error also mentions that the ext-sodium extension is missing. If you don't require this extension for your project, you can use the --ignore-platform-req flag to temporarily ignore the requirement for the ext-sodium extension:

```
composer require laravel/passport --ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium
```

This should allow you to install Laravel Passport without considering the missing ext-sodium extension.

Comment: The application wouldn't have complained about it missing if it wasn't required. 

Answer (score 1):

I use only `composer require laravel/passport:11.8.8 --with-all-dependencies` command it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it.

You first type the command `composer require league/oauth2-server ^8.5.3` and then you type again `composer require laravel/passport:11.8.8 --with-all-dependencies`

Leave a comment if it worked and mark as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If all   answers don't solve your problem get the latest version of composer.

Answer (score 0):

First remove composer.lock file.
Then try with composer require laravel/passport again. This worked for me. I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this command i hope this will work laravel 11 and latest version

```
php artisan install:api --passport
```

Answer (score -1):

composer require laravel/passport --ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium

[image]

Comment: Please provide textual information as text instead of as a picture of text.

Comment: "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/passport": "^11.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },

Comment: Please [edit] to provide textual informastion in appropriate formatting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting